# cleaning R memory: Intro to finance with R

Tags: r, rstudio

I am currently working on R and bought a book. There are some codes in there and it used to work in Rstudio as well as Visual Studio RTVS.

The following code plots a graph

```
frontier <- function(assets) {

return <- log(tail(assets, -1) / head(assets, -1))
Q <- cov(return)
n <- ncol(assets)
r <- colMeans(return)
Q1 <- rbind(Q, rep(1, n), r)
Q1 <- cbind(Q1, rbind(t(tail(Q1, 2)), matrix(0, 2, 2)))
rbase <- seq(min(r), max(r), length = 100)
s <- sapply(rbase, function(x) {
    y <- head(solve(Q1, c(rep(0, n), 1, x)), n)
    y %*% Q %*% y
})
plot(s, rbase, xlab = 'Return', ylab = 'Variance')
}
```

All of a sudden it does not graph this any longer. 
I used jupyter notebook and it did work online. My suspicion is that there is something wrong with the memory of RStudio but I cannot say for sure.
Should I re-install Rstudio?
thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The newer versions of RStudio act similarly to a jupyter notebook placing the output chunk into the code window, rather than the console window or viewer pane. It can be really easy to overlook this if you are not accustomed to it. These settings can be changed. I would double-check the settings first.

If that does not work, I would suggest clearing all of the items from the viewer pane, as well as clearing all items from the work space and running your code again.

## Edit:

Are you seeing the following code chunk being output in line with the code like the image below?

[image]

Click the sprocket-like icon next to knit:

[image]

Change it from inline with code to output in console:

[image]

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for this. how can I check the settings, please? Tools->Options. From there how can I check it? Also, I am not able to see the full window. with that I mean that I am not able to scroll down completely. your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Alex, this is much appreciated. Meanwhile I just cleared the graph plot pane and increased the ze and it worked. I can see my graph. I am not sure how to solved this problem in Visual Studio, which at some in time I to set as my default editor. For now I will stick to Rstudio.

Comment: Great. If you feel that this answer solved your problem, please select it as the answer.